# Как применить несколько функций-замыканий к одному событию?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Как вызвать по событию onclick сразу две функции? По одной все работает, но не могу понять, как же вызвать обе сразу из-под одной внешней функции-обертки?

Смысл в том, что я хочу создать универсальные функции без внешних переменных и чтобы каждая функция выполняла только свою конкретную задачу.

```
const changeColor = function(){
    const colors = ['magenta', 'cyan', 'firebrick', 'springgreen', 'skyblue'];
    let currentColor = 0;
    return function(){
        if(currentColor == colors.length){currentColor = 0};
        this.style.background = colors[currentColor++];
    }
}
const counter = function(){
    let count = 0;
    return function(){
        this.innerHTML = count; 
        count++;
    }
}
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.onclick = function(){    
    changeColor();            //Как применить эти две функции?
    counter(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для добавления нескольких обработчиков можно воспользоваться методом [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
const changeColor = function() {
  const colors = ['magenta', 'cyan', 'firebrick', 'springgreen', 'skyblue'];
  let currentColor = 0;
  return function() {
    if (currentColor == colors.length) {
      currentColor = 0
    };
    this.style.background = colors[currentColor++];
  }
}
const counter = function() {
  let count = 0;
  return function() {
    this.innerHTML = count;
    count++;
  }
}
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeColor());
button.addEventListener('click', counter());
```

```html
<button id="button">Нажми меня</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это то что я искал!