# Можно ли назначить на одну кнопку в HTML и выполнение функции, и переход на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, html

Условно есть кнопка на странице и есть функция, написанная на JS. Через `onclick` не составляет труда выполнить функцию или перейти на страницу, но только по отдельности. Что посоветуете для того, чтобы всё делалось в один клик?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов: [Как применить несколько функций-замыканий к одному событию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1097573/288409) и [Как сделать редирект на любой URI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/640996/288409).

Answer (score 1):

ничего сложного, jquery в помощь)

```js
    function go() {
        alert('ок')
        location.href = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/';
    }
```

```html
<div onmousedown="go()">клик</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. **Просто использовал** `onclick` **и** `onmousedown` **для кнопки**. У меня это не работало из за того, что накосячил в своём проекте с БД.